# a href not taking me to a page that is specified

Tags: html, hyperlink, cpanel, file-manager

I have an issue within my HTML when using an `<a href>`.

The issue is no matter what I put in it, it just is not working -

within my code i have:

```
<a href="/blog">Blog</a>
```

No matter how much I have tried, I cannot get this to work for some reason. The files are in the same directory so its not a fault of them being in separate folders. The page also works when I open it in my local machine, but not once it is in my file manager/ on my server etc as I am just getting a 404 error. Everything is also spelled correctly.

I have many other links throughout the code, but for some stupid reason this just refuses to work and I have spent the best part of 2 hours constantly googling and trying many different things. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the diacritical mark from the "a"?

Comment: Yeah, i only put that in the forum as it kept making a link - it is not there in my code :)

Comment: Ah okay, I think the only other area I would look is the link itself "/blog", try using a different link with a complete address first.